# How do i generate numpy linspace type numpy zeros array for initialization?

Tags: python, numpy

While generating a linspace array in Numpy we get an array of the form (len(array), ), i.e. it doesn't have any 2nd dimension. How do I generate a similar array and initialize it using Numpy zeros? Because it takes a 2nd argument, like 1, so I get (len(array), 1) while initializing, which I wanted to avoid if possible.

Eg. np.linspace(0,10,5) = [0, 2.5, 5, 7.5, 10] ;
It's array dimension is **(5, )**.

On the other hand, a zeros array is defined as np.zeros(**(5,1)**) and our output is a vector [0 0 0 0 0] ^ (Transpose). I wanted to be a flat array not like a vector.

Is there a way?

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me what you want to achieve. Please updated with an example with input and *expected* output.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Is it fine now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your first argument (5,1) is defining the shape of the array as a 5x1 explicitly 2d shape.  Just pass (5,), or more explicitly as follows:

```
import numpy as np
z = np.zeros(shape=(5,), dtype=float)
print(z)
print(z.shape)
```

output is:

```
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
(5,)
```

Comment: Use `shape=5` or `shape=(5,)`.  The 2nd is a 1 element tuple.